# When enabling organizational sharing in Exchange for free/busy, events are no longer accepted tentatively

Tags: exchange

We have organization A, and organization B, both using Exchange Online.

We wish to allow sharing of busy/free between the orgs.

To test this, I set org B's domain as an enabled shared domain, within org A, within the dialog below.

[image: Org sharing]

We have not altered org B at all yet.

What we now notice, is that if we invite a user in org A, and org B, to an event, then it no longer immediately goes into the user's calendar as tentative.  The event is missing.

Removing the sharing setting restored that functionality.

Is there a known reason for this? We don't wish to lose that functionality.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I have test on my side, it worked as expected. So I suggest you configure the sharing on both sides and test again. My settings are as below:
[image]

Comment: Thanks. My scenario was around when sharing from one side only.

Comment: I mean you could check if the issue persist when you share from both side.

Comment: No, both sides sharing fixes the issue.

Comment: So this issue is caused by different configuration on two sides.